# checking which android version is on the device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-api-levels

I have an android app Iv'e built and in this app I would like to check what is the android version of the device running the app and act accordingly.
Is there any way to check it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 android.os.Build.VERSION
```

This provides the current version

Answer (score -1):

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // only for gingerbread and newer versions 
}